# NonlinearModelFit with NDSolve

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have a series of data:

```
 data={{x1(t),y1(t)},...,{xN(t),yN(t)}}
```

data represent a particle's orbit in the {x,y} plane. I would like to fit these observations with an orbit coming from two differential equations:

```
xt''[t]=f[x,y]
yt''[t]=g[x,y]
```

I would like to use NonlinearModel fit but I'm not able to define the model. The model would be given by {xt[t],yt[t]}; I should fit {x(t),y(t)} with {xt[t],yt[t]}, where the parameters are the initial conditions.
Have you any general suggestions on the syntax?

My example of code is the following:

```
 model[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{x, y, t}, 
 First[{x,y} /. Eq1, Eq2, x[0] == a, x'[0] == b, y[0] == c, 
 y'[0] == d}, {x, y}, {t, 1992.224, 2009.61}, 
 Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, 
 Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15,
 PrecisionGoal -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity]]]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[a, b, c, d][t], {{a, b, c, d}, t]

nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

But all I get is error message

```
NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value ... is not a list of real           numbers with dimensions {70} at... >>
```

Is there something to modify in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The field {xt'',yt''} is an acceleration field. Giving 2 initial conditions (e.g. initial position and velocity or the first 2 points) the trajectory is uniquely determined.
You may now define an error function: err that is the sum of the distances (or easier, the squares thereof) from your data points. And now you want to minimize err over 4 parameters (e.g. initial position:2 parameters initial velocity:2 parameters)

Comment: This answer would be made better if you can define the syntax using `code` that the OP is looking for. This answer is informative, however.

Comment: Should I also serve tee and cake?

Comment: Exactly. But I can't find such an exemple to help me.

Comment: I solved it minimizing a chi square variable with NMinimize.